# Hide HDD from Windows but not Linux

Tags: linux, windows, hard-drive

I have a PC with multiple HDD's, one HDD has Windows, one HDD has Linux, the rest are storage drives.

I want to only be able to access certain drives from certain OS's, is there any way to do this?

For example:

```
C = Windows

D = Linux

E = Storage

F = Storage

G = Storage
```

I want to be able to access E in Windows with F and G hidden.

I want to be able to access F and G in Linux with E hidden.

Answer (score 1):

On windows:
Start button -> Control Panel -> System and Security -> Administrative Tools ->Computer Management

On the left, under "Storage" go to `Disk Management`.

Make a right click the mounted drive that you want to remove and then click `Change Drive Letter and Paths`.

Click `Remove`, and then click `Yes`.

Windows will remember the setting you just made, so it won't appears on next reboot

On Linux manage `/etc/fstab` 
See `man 5 fstab` for details how to manage it